# how to join two tables using eloquent or query builder

Tags: php, sql, laravel, eloquent

I have this query which basically lists topics that two users have in common.

```
$subcommon= SubjectUser::selectRaw('topic_id, count(topic_id) AS aggregate')
     ->whereIn('user_id', [4, 2])->groupBy('topic_id')
     ->having('aggregate','>',1)->get();
```

For example the query result for the table below would be

```
{"topic_id":3,"aggregate":1}
```

tableone

```
id|user_id|topic_id
 1|2      |3
 2|4      |3
 3|5      |1
```

I have another table(tabletwo) that also has topic_id which I would like to join so that I get the query result of row 2 from the second table. How would I go about doing this?

tabletwo

```
id|group_id|topic_id
 1|6      |2
 2|7      |3
 3|7      |1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('tableone')->join('tabletwo', function($join) {
    $join->on(tableone.topic_id, '=', tabletwo.topic_id);
})->get();
```

Comment: can I still join the `SubjectUser` model to a table name because i cant seem to get this working

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$subcommon= DB::table('tableone')
     ->selectRaw('topic_id, count(topic_id) AS aggregate')
     ->join('tabletwo','tabletwo.topic_id', '=', 'tableone.topic_id')
     ->whereIn('user_id', [4, 2])
     ->groupBy('tableone.topic_id')
     ->having('aggregate','>',1)
     ->get();
```